# Open-Source C or C++ Embedded relational database (copy source to deploy)

Tags: c++, c, database, embeddable

I have a cross platform project where the client gets the code, but doesn't want to resolve any dependencies. The requirements are best solved with a relational database, so it seems I need to copy the source of an embeddable relational database into my program and compile the library directly into the executable or as part of the project.

Is there a relational embeddable database which has a permissive license so that I can copy the source directly into the project? Which one has the smallest code base? Ideally I'm thinking of one C source file and one header that I can copy into the program and start using immediately.

Comment: and two seconds later I find SQLite 3 amalgamation source which is basically what I described. http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org)

They have “amalgamation” source distribution which is one C source file, which can be included into a project and used right away.

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) comes to mind.